# Mix python output and markdown in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to show the result of a python computation and have some explanation of it in Markdown. This seems like a fairly simple operation, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Is there any way to do this without installing any extensions to Jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

In the **toolbar** (see image here http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/jupyter-notebook-default.png), you can set the cell as Markdown in the drop down menu for explanatory text.

Comment: I want to be able to have markdown and python in the same cell, so I can talk about multiple results in the same cell. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Could you provide an example about how this should look like?

Answer (score 2):

Would it suffice if you yourself didn't have to personally handle the installations to Jupyter?

I know OP says specifically, without installing an extension, but what is described is addressed with the `Python-Markdown` extension, see [here](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html). And this question comes up at the top of the list when one Googles "jupyter mix markdown and python print cell".

You can easily use Python-Markdown in an active notebook launched via the MyBinder system from [here](https://beta.mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/jupyter-extension/master?filepath=index.ipynb); the repo for that is [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension) if you want to fork it and further adapt it by adding your own notebooks.